# Passing variable from one function to another function in same controller (laravel 5)

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want the `$searchName` value passed to the `executeMapSearch()` function. 
And run the query in `executeMapSearch()` function.

This is my `MainController` class.
In the `search()` function , I am getting the `$name` value from a Blade View.

```
class MainController extends Controller {

    public function search() {
        $name = Input::get('input-16');
        $searchName = $name . "%";
        //some code
    }

    public function executeMapSearch() {
        $markers = DB::table('markers')
            ->leftJoin('locations','markers.locations_id', '=', 'locations.id')
            ->select('markers.*')
            ->whereRaw('locations.name LIKE "'.$searchName.'"')
            ->get();

        return View::make('main.results')
            ->with('title','marks')
            ->with('mark',$markers);
    }
}
```

My Route file is as follows:

```
Route::any('main/search', 'Main\MainController@search');
Route::any('main/executeMapSearch', 'Main\MainController@executeMapSearch');
```

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something here? Should be able to just set the controller like so:

`public function executeMapSearch($searchname)`

Then in `search()`

`return $this->executeMapSearch($searchname);`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't understand if you really need to use `search` in controller. Looking at your code, you don't need at all:

```
Route::any('main/search', 'Main\MainController@search');
```

but you put only a piece of code so i's hard to say.

If you want to run any function in your controller, you can use it the same as you use methods in PHP classes, so in this case, you could use:

```
->whereRaw('locations.name LIKE "'.$this->search().'"')
```

instead of

```
->whereRaw('locations.name LIKE "'.$searchName.'"')
```

However if your `search` method returns Response, you should probably create one extra function to calculate `searchName` only and use it in both `search` and `executeMapSearch` methods.

Comment: Thank You, actually i had a SQL Query and $searchName for where clause in search(). The result from that SQL query is return to view.